# Remove period between DOI and urldate

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, urls, doi

Whenever a DOI is available, I provide it instead of a URL in my bibliography. In both cases, I need to provide the access date (`urldate` field) as well.
My problem: `biblatex` puts a period after the DOI, so that the ensuing *visited on* is capitalized, but no period after the URL (so no capitalization). This does not look homogenous.

How can I remove the period after the DOI?

MWE:

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    backend = biber,
    style = authortitle,
    ]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a,
author = {Lily},
title = {Trees},
journaltitle = {Journal of Trees},
year = {2015},
url = {www.trees.com},
urldate = {2016-11-21},
}

@article{b,
author = {John},
title = {Flowers},
journaltitle = {Journal of Flowers},
year = {2015},
doi = {17.7-31893.23},
urldate = {2016-11-21},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are. Just redefine the bibmacro `doi+eprint+url`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    backend = biber,
    style = authortitle,
    ]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a,
author = {Lily},
title = {Trees},
journaltitle = {Journal of Trees},
year = {2015},
url = {www.trees.com},
urldate = {2016-11-21},
}

@article{b,
author = {John},
title = {Flowers},
journaltitle = {Journal of Flowers},
year = {2015},
doi = {17.7-31893.23},
urldate = {2016-11-21},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, perfect! I had gotten to the `doi+eprint+url` bibmacro, but didn’t know how to modify it. (I guess I could have put that in the question as well.) So you changed `\newunit\newblock` to `\setunit{\addspace}\newblock`. Looks like I’ll have to read up on units and blocks in `biblatex`, or is there a simple explanation of these concepts?

Comment: It's fairly simple: units are groups in the bibliography, and they're separated by a default punctuation ( `\adddot\addspace`). It's explained in §4.7 of the documentation, pp. 209–213.

Comment: I implemented this solution, but for some reason, it removes the period after the urldate in my MWE. Also, for some strange reason it removed the period after the year as well:  https://www.overleaf.com/6514453265gbtcvtrmpjnw